# Is there a way to guarantee hierarchical output from NetworkX?

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to produce a flow diagram of a **tree** structure. I've been able to create representative graphs with networkx, but I need a way to show the **tree** structure when I output a plot. I'm using matplotlib.pylab to plot the graph.

I need to show the data in a structure similar to what is shown [here](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Gallery/directed/Genetic_Programming.html). Although I don't have sub-graphs.

How can I guarantee a structure like that?

Examples for the unbelievers:

[image: Various NetworkX layouts]

I've been able to show the graphs with pylab and graphviz, but neither offer the tree structure I'm looking for. I've tried every layout networkx has to offer, but none of them show a **hierarchy**. I've just not sure what **options/mode** to give it **OR** if I need to use weights. Any suggestions would help a bunch.

@jterrace:

Here's a rough outline of what I used to produce the plots above. I've added some labels, but other than that it's the same.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node("ROOT")

for i in xrange(5):
    G.add_node("Child_%i" % i)
    G.add_node("Grandchild_%i" % i)
    G.add_node("Greatgrandchild_%i" % i)

    G.add_edge("ROOT", "Child_%i" % i)
    G.add_edge("Child_%i" % i, "Grandchild_%i" % i)
    G.add_edge("Grandchild_%i" % i, "Greatgrandchild_%i" % i)

plt.title("draw_networkx")
nx.draw_networkx(G)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 146, accepted):

If you use a directed graph then the Graphviz dot layout will do something like you want with the tree.  Here is some code similar to the above solutions that shows how to do that

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_node("ROOT")

for i in range(5):
    G.add_node("Child_%i" % i)
    G.add_node("Grandchild_%i" % i)
    G.add_node("Greatgrandchild_%i" % i)

    G.add_edge("ROOT", "Child_%i" % i)
    G.add_edge("Child_%i" % i, "Grandchild_%i" % i)
    G.add_edge("Grandchild_%i" % i, "Greatgrandchild_%i" % i)

# write dot file to use with graphviz
# run "dot -Tpng test.dot >test.png"
nx.nx_agraph.write_dot(G,'test.dot')

# same layout using matplotlib with no labels
plt.title('draw_networkx')
pos=graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=False, arrows=False)
plt.savefig('nx_test.png')
```

[image: Graphviz output]

[image: NetworkX/Matplotlib output]

**UPDATED**

Here is a version updated for networkx-2.0 (and with upcoming networkx-2.1 draws arrows too).

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot, graphviz_layout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_node("ROOT")

for i in range(5):
    G.add_node("Child_%i" % i)
    G.add_node("Grandchild_%i" % i)
    G.add_node("Greatgrandchild_%i" % i)

    G.add_edge("ROOT", "Child_%i" % i)
    G.add_edge("Child_%i" % i, "Grandchild_%i" % i)
    G.add_edge("Grandchild_%i" % i, "Greatgrandchild_%i" % i)

# write dot file to use with graphviz
# run "dot -Tpng test.dot >test.png"
write_dot(G,'test.dot')

# same layout using matplotlib with no labels
plt.title('draw_networkx')
pos =graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=False, arrows=True)
plt.savefig('nx_test.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Ah ha! So all I needed was a directed graph with the 'dot' layout. I knew it was something very small. Thanks a lot Aric!

Comment: Is there any good way to label the nodes ascendingly? By that I mean, I create a graph `g = nx.full_rary_tree(2, 10)` If I print the edges I get: `[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), ... ]` but it will visualize them in a different order...

Comment: What ordering do you want? See bfs_edges() and dfs_edges().

Comment: PyGrapviz works with Python 3 and this code will work with Python 3.

Comment: also if you encounter any problem installing `pygraphviz` in regular ways, try `pip install --install-option="--include-path=/usr/local/include/" --install-option="--library-path=/usr/local/lib/" pygraphviz`

Comment: @Rotail This worked for me after I installed `graphviz` (in my case using `brew install graphviz`).

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx.drawing'; 'networkx' is not a package. networkx already installed

Comment: `graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')` gives `OSError: Format: "dot" not recognized. Use one of:
` error.

Comment: I tried so many different ways to make a large graph. This was by far the best.

Answer (score 11):

You can use pygraphviz to get close:

```
>>> import pygraphviz
>>> import networkx
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_node("ROOT")
>>> for i in xrange(5):
...     G.add_node("Child_%i" % i)
...     G.add_node("Grandchild_%i" % i)
...     G.add_node("Greatgrandchild_%i" % i)
...     G.add_edge("ROOT", "Child_%i" % i)
...     G.add_edge("Child_%i" % i, "Grandchild_%i" % i)
...     G.add_edge("Grandchild_%i" % i, "Greatgrandchild_%i" % i)

>>> A = nx.to_agraph(G)
>>> A.layout('dot', args='-Nfontsize=10 -Nwidth=".2" -Nheight=".2" -Nmargin=0 -Gfontsize=8')
>>> A.draw('test.png')
```

Result:
[image]

Note I copied the graphviz options from the link you posted above. I'm not sure why the 4th child is drawn on top instead of in strictly vertical format. Maybe someone who knows more about the Graphviz options can help with that.

Comment: thanks. This was exactly what I was seeing when I tried it. I find it somewhat strange why it produced something like this.

Comment: Note that in version 1.11 of networkx the api changed. The `to_agraph` function is now located in `nx.nx_agraph.to_agraph`.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure that child are always below their parents?

Comment: I don't understand where you have used that imported `pygraphviz`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [grandalf](https://github.com/bdcht/grandalf) for a python-only solution, if you don't want to install graphviz.

Also, this type of visualization is called a [layered graph drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing) or [Sugiyama-style graph drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing), which can display many kinds of graphs, including non-trees.

See [my answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64516717/6844235) for details and implementation.

Answer (score 1):

See also the hierarchical structures created by @Abdallah Sobehy, w/o the need to use any extra module/library (like 'pygraphviz'), at
[preserving the left and right child while printing python graphs using networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439810/preserving-the-left-and-right-child-while-printing-python-graphs-using-networkx)

Maybe the graph is not so nice as the above, but it does the requested job!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it manually just with only networkx. Traverse tree and for each children coordinate x change as if right parent.x+1/np.log(y_coord + 1) if left parent.x-1... and y = parent.y - 1 Or any other algorithm to get coord and eg. See image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfMfB.png).

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
coord = {0: [8, 0], 2: [9, -1], 1: [8, -2], 4: [10, -2], 3: [9, -3], 5: [11, -3]}
eg = [[0, 2], [2, 1], [2, 4], [4, 3], [4, 5]]
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(eg) 
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_size=1500, node_color="skyblue", pos=coord) 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers recommend using `graphviz_layout()`, but that requires the use of the additional library `pygraphviz`. There is a way to create hierarchical graphs using only `NetworkX` and `matplotlib` by using `NetworkX`'s `multipartite_layout()`. This layout allows you to create hierarchical graphs by specifying nodes to be in certain `subset`s which will be columns or rows depending if the `align` parameter is `"horizontal"` or `"vertical"`. I created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/djlouie/NetworkX-Multiparte-Demo) demonstrating this.

By editing the code from the repository a little, we can create a hierarchical tree graph.

[image: Resulting Tree Graph (Simple Branches Similar to the Other Answers)]

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tree_dict = {
    1: {
        "Group 1.1":"Root",
        "Group 1.2":"Root",
        "Group 1.3":"Root",
        "Group 1.4":"Root",
        "Group 1.5":"Root"
        },
    2: {
        "Group 2.1":"Group 1.1",
        "Group 2.2":"Group 1.2",
        "Group 2.3":"Group 1.3",
        "Group 2.4":"Group 1.4",
        "Group 2.5":"Group 1.5"
        },
    3: {
        "Group 3.1":"Group 2.1",
        "Group 3.2":"Group 2.2",
        "Group 3.3":"Group 2.3",
        "Group 3.4":"Group 2.4",
        "Group 3.5":"Group 2.5"
        },
    4: {
        "Group 4.1":"Group 3.1",
        "Group 4.2":"Group 3.2",
        "Group 4.3":"Group 3.3",
        "Group 4.4":"Group 3.4",
        "Group 4.5":"Group 3.5"
        }
    }

# Create a NextworkX directed graph
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from(['Root'], subset=4)
g.add_nodes_from(tree_dict[1].keys(), subset=3)
g.add_nodes_from(tree_dict[2].keys(), subset=2)
g.add_nodes_from(tree_dict[3].keys(), subset=1)
g.add_nodes_from(tree_dict[4].keys(), subset=0)

# Add Title to Plot
plt.title('Multipartite Tree Graph')

# Create a list of the edges
edges = []
for subset_stuff in tree_dict.values():
    for node, prev_node in subset_stuff.items():
        edges.append((prev_node, node))

# Draw the nodes with the multipartite layout
pos = nx.multipartite_layout(g, align='horizontal')
nx.draw(g, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=1500, font_size=8)

# Draw the edges with the multipartite layout
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos, edgelist=edges, arrows=True, node_size=1500)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting Tree Graph (More Complex Branches)]

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tree_dict = {
        1: {
            "Group 1.1":"Root",
            "Group 1.2":"Root",
            "Group 1.3":"Root"
            },
        2: {
            "Group 2.1":"Group 1.1",
            "Group 2.2":"Group 1.2",
            "Group 2.3":"Group 1.3"
            },
        3: {
            "Group 3.1":"Group 2.2",
            "Group 3.2":"Group 2.2",
            "Group 3.3":"Group 2.3",
            "Group 3.4":"Group 2.3",
            },
        4: {
            "Group 4.1":"Group 3.4",
            "Group 4.2":"Group 3.4"
            }
        }

# Create a NextworkX directed graph
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from(['Root'], subset=4)
g.add_nodes_from(tree_dict[1].keys(), subset=3)
g.add_nodes_from(tree_dict[2].keys(), subset=2)
g.add_nodes_from(tree_dict[3].keys(), subset=1)
g.add_nodes_from(tree_dict[4].keys(), subset=0)

# Add Title to Plot
plt.title('Multipartite Tree Graph')

# Create a list of the edges
edges = []
for subset_stuff in tree_dict.values():
    for node, prev_node in subset_stuff.items():
        edges.append((prev_node, node))

# Draw the nodes with the multipartite layout
pos = nx.multipartite_layout(g, align='horizontal')
nx.draw(g, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=1500, font_size=8)

# Draw the edges with the multipartite layout
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos, edgelist=edges, arrows=True, node_size=1500)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```