# Drawing colored trees with NetworkX

Tags: python, matplotlib, tree, graphviz, networkx

NOTE -- This is a complete rewrite of the previous question, which I think was too complex. It presents a much simpler version which, if I can solve, will result in progress.

I have adapted my code from this SO answer: [Is there a way to guarantee hierarchical output from NetworkX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479624/is-there-a-way-to-guarantee-hierarchical-output-from-networkx)

With the following very simple code, I get strange coloring behavior.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node("ROOT")

for i in xrange(1):
    for j in range(1):
        G.add_node(str(j)+"_%i" % i, )        
        if j ==0:
            G.add_edge("ROOT", str(j)+"_%i" % i)
        else:
            G.add_edge(str(j-1)+"_%i" %i, str(j)+"_%i" % i)

pos=nx.graphviz_layout(G,prog='dot')

for i in xrange(1):
    nodelist = ['ROOT']
    for j in range(1):
        nodelist.append(str(j)+"_%i" % i )
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, nodelist=nodelist, cmap=plt.get_cmap('Set3'), node_color=[0,1])
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos,arrows=True)

limits=plt.axis('off')
```

It seems to NOT matter what values I give for the `node_color`, only whether the values are different or not. For example, with `node_color = [0,1]`, I get the exact same behavior as when it is `[0,.1]`, or `[0,1000]`. (Why? The colormap takes values between 0 and 1).

[image]

However if I change the colormap, the colors DO change. For example:

[image]

And if I set `node_color = [3,3]` (or any two values which are the same), I always get the same thing, the nodes are colored identically.

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: A self-contained example would help, as well as knowing what `nodecolors` and `x` are in your function.

Comment: Added all the other pieces involved. (I only omitted them to begin with because they are a bit involved and I am new to NetworkX, so thought I might be making a newbie error.) I think this is as self-contained as I can make the question!

Comment: Can you add the output for some other values of "time"?

Comment: There you go, did times 0,1 and 2.

Comment: I've completely rewritten the question and made it much simpler. I hope this helps to identify what is actually going on. Nobody needs to know about all that other stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before getting to the colormap, the node color values are normalized to the interval [0, 1]. This is presumably meant to use the full range of colors, regardless of the range of the values given. To use a different interval for scaling, you can set the `vmin` and `vmax` parameters:

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, nodelist, cmap=plt.get_cmap('Set3'),
                       node_color=[0,1], vmin=0, vmax=100)
```

---

A detailed explanation:

From the description of the **node_color** parameter in the [draw_networkx_nodes() docs](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html?highlight=node_color):

> If numeric values
>   are specified they will be mapped to colors using the cmap and
>   vmin,vmax parameters. See matplotlib.scatter for more details.

Unfortunately, these docs don't do a good job of describing the behaviour of `vmin` and `vmax`. But the [reference for matplotlib.scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) does cover it more thouroughly:

> vmin and vmax are used in conjunction with norm to normalize luminance data. **If either are None, the min and max of the color array is used.**

So, the minimum of the node_color array you pass is, by default, mapped to 0 on the colormap, and the maximum to 1. Everything in between is mapped to the interval [0.0,1.0] using a linear mapping (this is called *normalization* or *[feature scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling)*). Here are some examples, going from `node_color` to points in the colormap's domain:

- [0, 0.1] → [0, 1]
- [0, 1000] → [0, 1]
- [0, 200, 1000] → [0, 0.2, 1]
- [10, 15, 20] → [0, 0.5, 1]
- [0, 0] → [0,0] *(or it could be [1,1]; I didn't actually run this)*

Comment: `vmax` and `vmin` are the answer, for some reason I don't comprehend. Your answer does not explain why I get the same results when I say `node_color = [0,1]` and `node_color=[0,.1]` (unless I missed something). HOWEVER, when I set `vmax=1` and `vmin=0`, the colormap suddenly works. This suggests there is something a little off with the defaults? Thanks for putting me on the right track. Incidentally, I asked a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871827/colormap-not-working-in-networkx If you would like to answer it as well, I would be happy to accept.

Comment: I edited the answer to add some examples, but I might have misunderstood what you're confused about. I think the colormap *does* "work" -- it's just that *by default, `vmax` is set to the maximum of `node_color`*.