# Using networkX to output a tree structure

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am using networkX to generate a tree structure as follows (I am following the [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479624/is-there-a-way-to-guarantee-hierarchical-output-from-networkx)).

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_node("ROOT")
for i in range(5):
    G.add_node("Child_%i" % i)
    G.add_node("Grandchild_%i" % i)
    G.add_node("Greatgrandchild_%i" % i)

    G.add_edge("ROOT", "Child_%i" % i)
    G.add_edge("Child_%i" % i, "Grandchild_%i" % i)
    G.add_edge("Grandchild_%i" % i, "Greatgrandchild_%i" % i)

# write dot file to use with graphviz
# run "dot -Tpng test.dot >test.png"
nx.write_dot(G,'test.dot')

# same layout using matplotlib with no labels
plt.title('draw_networkx')
pos=nx.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=False, arrows=False)
plt.savefig('nx_test.png')
```

I want to draw a tree as in the following figure.
[image]

However, I am getting an error saying `AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'write_dot'`. My networkx version is 1.11 (using conda). I tried different [hacks](https://github.com/nipy/nipype/issues/1350), but none of them worked.

So, I am interested in knowing if there is another way of drawing tree structures using networkx to get an output similar to the one mentioned in the figure. Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw digraph entirely with `pygraphviz`.

Following  steps needs to be followed first as `pygraphviz` does not work without `graphviz` (as of now).

1. Download graphviz-2.38.msi from http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php and install
2. Download the 2.7 or 3.4 `pygraphviz` wheel file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygraphviz
3. Navigate to the directory that you downloaded the wheel file  and run your platform specific wheel
   `pip install pygraphviz‑1.3.1‑cp34‑none‑win32.whl`
4. Add `dot.exe` to host path 
   e.g. on windows control-panel ->system -> edit environment variables -> Modify PATH

After that `dot` and `png` files can be created as below.

**Working Code**

```
import pygraphviz as pgv

G=pgv.AGraph(directed=True)

#Attributes can be added when adding nodes or edge
G.add_node("ROOT", color='red')
for i in range(5):
    G.add_node("Child_%i" % i, color='blue')
    G.add_node("Grandchild_%i" % i, color='blue')
    G.add_node("Greatgrandchild_%i" % i, color='blue')

    G.add_edge("ROOT", "Child_%i" % i, color='blue')
    G.add_edge("Child_%i" % i, "Grandchild_%i" % i, color='blue')
    G.add_edge("Grandchild_%i" % i, "Greatgrandchild_%i" % i, color='blue')

# write to a dot file
G.write('test.dot')

#create a png file
G.layout(prog='dot') # use dot
G.draw('file.png')
```

**PNG File**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this issue was solved on networkx 2.x, but before that you should be explicit import of the function like this.

```
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot
```

or

```
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import write_dot
```

I hope this works.